# Recycler view onBindViewHolder is repeating a weird pattern

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am working on a messaging app which has swipe option to mute or lock conversations, when we press the mute or lock button, small icons are displayed on Recycler view item,  but when I try to mute or even lock a certain message it shows the icons on that item but the icons also appears on elements after every 10 counts.

For Example, If I lock the message at position 1, element at position 12 also shows the same icons, if I removed the icon from the first position, icons from the later position is also removed. Any help would be highly appreciated as I am new to android development and still trying to learn.

Picture:

[image]

Recycler view items xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/sample1"
    >
    <!-- Bottom View Start-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftWrapper"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#365cf5"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/panelArchieve"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/archieve"
                android:src="@drawable/archieve"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#d20909"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/trash"
                android:src="@drawable/trash"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper_2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#365dea"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/panelLock"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lock"
                android:src="@drawable/lock"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#0e9b04"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:id="@+id/panelMute"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mute"
                android:src="@drawable/mute"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Bottom View End-->

    <!-- Surface View Start -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/rv_img_name"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:padding="3dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/rv_title"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rv_img_name"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rv_img_name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/rv_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rv_title"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rv_title"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rv_title"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rv_title"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgMute"
                android:src="@drawable/mute"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rv_title"


                 />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgLock"
                android:src="@drawable/lock"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgMute" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Surface View End -->
</com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    //final int position = Texty.position;
    final tblMsgs name = mDataset.get(position);
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
            viewHolder.btnDel.setTag("trash");
            viewHolder.btnDel.setImageResource(R.drawable.trash);
        }
    });

    //Double click
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.setOnDoubleClickListener(new SwipeLayout.DoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(SwipeLayout layout, boolean surface) {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //Open conversation.
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(viewHolder.swipeLayout.getOpenStatus() == SwipeLayout.Status.Open) {
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                viewHolder.btnDel.setTag("trash");
                viewHolder.btnDel.setImageResource(R.drawable.trash);
            }
            else{ //Open conversation
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    //Delete
    viewHolder.panelDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (viewHolder.btnDel.getTag().equals("trash")){
                viewHolder.btnDel.setTag("del");
                viewHolder.btnDel.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
                YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(view.findViewById(R.id.trash));
            }
            else  if (viewHolder.btnDel.getTag().equals("del")){
                viewHolder.btnDel.setTag("trash");
                //viewHolder.btnDel.setImageResource(R.drawable.trash);
                ds.deleteChat(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
                mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
                mDataset.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size());
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
            }
        }
    });


    //Mute/Unmute
    viewHolder.panelMute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Mute unmute pos: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (viewHolder.btnMute.getTag().equals("bell")){
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                viewHolder.imgMute.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.btnMute.setTag("mute");
                viewHolder.btnMute.setImageResource(R.drawable.mute);
                ds.unMute(name.getrNumber());
            }
            else{

                //Save Sender Settings
                ds.open();
                if(ds.selectCount_tblSender(name.getrNumber()) ==  0){
                    //Log.i(Log_tag, "Saving settings for " + viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
                    tblSender sndr = new tblSender();
                    sndr.setNumber(name.getrNumber());
                    ds.create_tblSender(sndr);
                }

                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                viewHolder.imgMute.setImageResource(R.drawable.mute);
                viewHolder.imgMute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(view.findViewById(R.id.imgMute));
                viewHolder.btnMute.setTag("bell");
                //YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(view.findViewById(R.id.mute));
                ds.mute(name.getrNumber());
                viewHolder.btnMute.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell);
            }
            //mItemManger.closeAllItems();
            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + viewHolder.textViewPos.getText().toString() + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //Lock / Unlock
    viewHolder.panelLock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (viewHolder.btnLock.getTag().equals("locked")){
                //Save Sender Settings
                ds.open();
                if(ds.selectCount_tblSender(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString()) ==  0){
                    //Log.i(Log_tag, "Saving settings for " + viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
                    tblSender sndr = new tblSender();
                    sndr.setNumber(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
                    ds.create_tblSender(sndr);
                }
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                viewHolder.imgLock.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock);
                viewHolder.imgLock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(view.findViewById(R.id.imgLock));
                viewHolder.btnLock.setTag("unlocked");
                viewHolder.btnLock.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlock);
                //YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(view.findViewById(R.id.lock));
                ds.Lock(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
            }
            else{
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                viewHolder.imgLock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.btnLock.setTag("locked");
                viewHolder.btnLock.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock);
                ds.unLock(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
            }
            //mItemManger.closeAllItems();
        }
    });

    //Archieve
    viewHolder.panelArchieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDataset.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size());
            mItemManger.closeAllItems();

            ds.open();
            if(ds.selectCount_tblSender(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString()) ==  0){
                //Log.i(Log_tag, "Saving settings for " + viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
                tblSender sndr = new tblSender();
                sndr.setNumber(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());
                ds.create_tblSender(sndr);
            }
            ds.archieve(viewHolder.textViewPos.getTag().toString());

        }
    });


    viewHolder.textViewPos.setText(name.getSenderName());
    viewHolder.textViewPos.setTag(name.getrNumber());
    viewHolder.textViewData.setText(name.getMessage().trim());
    //Log.i(Log_tag, "Msg: " +  name.getMessage().trim());
    //viewHolder.txtTime.setText(name.getTime());

    //Time Text
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String dateNowStr = formatter.format(date);
        Date dateNow = null;

        dateNow = formatter.parse(dateNowStr);

        String dateSmsStr = name.getTime().substring(0,10);
        Date dateSMS = formatter.parse(dateSmsStr);
        if (dateSMS.compareTo(dateNow)<0)
        {
            viewHolder.txtTime.setText(dateSmsStr.substring(0,10)); // + " " + name.getTime().substring(11,name.getTime().length()));
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.txtTime.setText(name.getTime().substring(11,name.getTime().length()));
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
    //int colorRandom = generator.getRandomColor(); // generate random color
    //int colorAlpha = generator.getColor(mDataset.get(position).getrName().substring(0,1));//(same key returns the same color)
    // declare the builder object once.
    TextDrawable.IBuilder builder = TextDrawable.builder()
            .beginConfig()
            .withBorder(0)
            .toUpperCase()
            .endConfig()
            .round();

    int greenColorValue = Color.parseColor("#FF457BDF");
    TextDrawable ic1 = builder.build(mDataset.get(position).getrName().substring(0,1), greenColorValue);
    viewHolder.imgName.setImageDrawable(ic1);
    if(ds.select_tblSender(name.getrNumber()).getIsMute() == 1){ //Mute sign
        Log.i(Log_tag, name.getrNumber() + " was muted at position " + position);
        viewHolder.btnMute.setTag("bell");
        viewHolder.btnMute.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell);
        viewHolder.imgMute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(ds.select_tblSender(name.getrNumber()).getIsProtected() == 1){ //Mute sign
        viewHolder.btnLock.setTag("unlocked");
        viewHolder.btnLock.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlock);
        viewHolder.imgLock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    mItemManger.bindView(viewHolder.itemView, position);
}
```

MainActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    updateBarHandler = new Handler();


    //Fill Inbox
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    // Layout Managers:
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    ds = new dataSource(this);
    activity = this;


    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(activity, listInboxAll);
    ((RecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);


    //All conversations
    GetAllMsgs task = new GetAllMsgs();
    task.execute();
}
```

GetAllMsgs()

```
 private class GetAllMsgs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
            Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(uriSMSURI, projection, null, null, "date DESC");
            int i = 0;
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                final String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                final String date = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
                final Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);
                //Log.i(Log_tag, "Msg: " + body + " from: " + address);
                address = address.trim();
                if(address.toString().startsWith("92"))
                {
                    address = address.toString().replace("92", "0");
                }
                else if(address.toString().startsWith("3")){
                    address = "0" + address;
                }
                else if(address.toString().startsWith("+92"))
                {
                    address = address.toString().replace("+92", "0");
                }
                final String nAdd = address;
                time = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(activity);
                if(time){
                    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy k:mm");
                }
                else{
                    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a");
                }

                String usr = getContactName(activity, nAdd);
                tblMsgs msg = new tblMsgs();
                msg.setMessage(body);
                msg.setSenderName(usr); //Fuzool hai for now
                msg.setIsSent(1);
                msg.setIsReply(0);
                msg.setIsUploaded(0);
                msg.setIsLocked(0);
                msg.setTime(dateFormat.format(timestamp));
                msg.setrName(usr); //Name from phone book
                msg.setrNumber(nAdd);
                msg.setTimeStamp(timestamp);
                //listInboxAll.add(msg);
                Texty.position = i;
                ((RecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).addnewItem(msg);
                i++;
                final int j = i;
                if(i % 5 == 0){
                    updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run () {
                            ((RecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).Update(j);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));

                        }
                    });
                }

                //listInboxAll.add(msg);
                //ds.create(msg);
            }
            return "done";
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(Log_tag, ex.getMessage());
            return "failed";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not digging through that much code.  Minimize it.  But most likely you forgot to set it to hide if the chat isn't muted.  Due to recycling if you set anything in any view, you must set it to the default in all other cases.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan you were right, Thanks :)

Comment: @Tasos everything is working fine now, I used tags to store values.

Comment: put what you done as an answer. It may help other people

Answer (score 0):

@Gabe Sechan solved my problem, I had to change the visibility of icons initially.